# Android uber ping request animation or component

Tags: android, animation

Can any one suggest me how to do circle animation and progress button like Uber driver pickup request in Android. If you can provide some code that will be good.

[image]

Comment: Thanks i got the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to this.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import com.circularseekbar.R;

public class CircularProgressBar extends View {

private Context mContext;
private Paint circleColor, innerColor, circleRing;
private int angle = 0, startAngle = 270, barWidth = 50, maxProgress = 100;


private int width, height, progress=1, tmpProgress=1, progressPercent;
private float innerRadius, outerRadius, adjustmentFactor=100;//The radius of the inner circle

private float cx, cy; //The circle's center X, Y coordinate

private float left, right, top, bottom, startPointX, startPointY, markPointX, markPointY;
private float dx, dy;//The X and Y coordinate for the top left corner of the marking drawable
private Bitmap progressMark, progressMarkPressed;

private RectF rect = new RectF();
{

    circleColor = new Paint();
    innerColor = new Paint();
    circleRing = new Paint();

    circleColor.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff33b5e5")); // Set default
    // progress
    // color to holo
    // blue.
    innerColor.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Set default background color to
    // black
    circleRing.setColor(Color.GRAY);// Set default background color to Gray

    circleColor.setAntiAlias(true);
    innerColor.setAntiAlias(true);
    circleRing.setAntiAlias(true);

    circleColor.setStrokeWidth(25);
    innerColor.setStrokeWidth(15);
    circleRing.setStrokeWidth(10);

    circleColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
}

public CircularProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mContext = context;
}

public CircularProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
}

public CircularProgressBar(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    width = getWidth(); // Get View Width
    height = getHeight();// Get View Height

    int size = (width > height) ? height : width; // Choose the smaller
    // between width and
    // height to make a
    // square

    cx = width / 2; // Center X for circle
    cy = height / 2; // Center Y for circle
    outerRadius = size / 2; // Radius of the outer circle

    innerRadius = outerRadius - barWidth; // Radius of the inner circle

    left = cx - outerRadius; // Calculate left bound of our rect
    right = cx + outerRadius;// Calculate right bound of our rect
    top = cy - outerRadius;// Calculate top bound of our rect
    bottom = cy + outerRadius;// Calculate bottom bound of our rect

    startPointX = cx; // 12 O'clock X coordinate
    startPointY = cy - outerRadius;// 12 O'clock Y coordinate
    markPointX = startPointX;// Initial locatino of the marker X coordinate
    markPointY = startPointY;// Initial locatino of the marker Y coordinate

    rect.set(left, top, right, bottom); // assign size to rect
}


@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, outerRadius, circleRing);
    canvas.drawArc(rect, startAngle, angle, true, circleColor);
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, innerRadius, innerColor);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

public int getAngle() {
    return angle;
}

public void setAngle(int angle) {
    //System.out.println("Angel "+angle);
    this.angle = angle;
    float donePercent = (((float) this.angle) / 360) * 100;
    float progress = (donePercent / 100) * getMaxProgress();
    setProgressPercent(Math.round(donePercent));
    setProgress(Math.round(progress));
}

public int getBarWidth() {
    return barWidth;
}

public void setBarWidth(int barWidth) {
    this.barWidth = barWidth;
}

public int getMaxProgress() {
    return maxProgress;
}

public void setMaxProgress(int maxProgress) {
    this.maxProgress = maxProgress;
}

public int getProgress() {
    return progress;
}

public void setProgress(int progress) {
    if (this.progress != progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        int newPercent = (this.progress * 100) / this.maxProgress;
        int newAngle = (newPercent * 360) / 100;
        this.setAngle(newAngle);
        this.setProgressPercent(newPercent);
    }
}

long mAnimStartTime;

Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Runnable mTick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        invalidate();
        update();
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100); // 20ms == 60fps
    }
};

public void update(){
    if(IS_ACTIVE){
        setProgress(tmpProgress);
        if(tmpProgress>maxProgress){
            stopAnimation();
        }
        tmpProgress++;
    }
}

boolean IS_ACTIVE=false;
public void startAnimation() {
    IS_ACTIVE=true;
    tmpProgress=1;
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTick);
    mHandler.post(mTick);
}

public void stopAnimation() {
    IS_ACTIVE=false;
    progress=1;
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTick);
}

public int getProgressPercent() {
    return progressPercent;
}

public void setProgressPercent(int progressPercent) {
    this.progressPercent = progressPercent;
}

public void setRingBackgroundColor(int color) {
    circleRing.setColor(color);
}

public void setBackGroundColor(int color) {
    innerColor.setColor(color);
}

public void setProgressColor(int color) {
    circleColor.setColor(color);
}

public float getAdjustmentFactor() {
    return adjustmentFactor;
}

public void setAdjustmentFactor(float adjustmentFactor) {
    this.adjustmentFactor = adjustmentFactor;
}
}
```